# dc.js - min value from group per day

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have the following data structure and would like to display a lineChart with the minimum value of 'amount' (group) by Day (of date) (dimension).

```
var data = [
 {date: "2014-01-01", amount: 10},
 {date: "2014-01-01", amount: 1},
 {date: "2014-01-15", amount: 0},
 {date: "2014-01-15", amount: 10 },
 {date: "2014-02-20", amount: 100 },
 {date: "2014-02-20", amount: 10 },
];
```

Where as I would normally be doing something along the following lines, I'm not sure how to find the min in the group.

```
var dateDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {return d3.time.day(d.date);});
var dateDimGroup = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.amount; })
```

Is this possible? I can't seem to find any examples of this so any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need to keep a custom grouping. The basic idea is that you maintain an array (ordered is best) of all the values in a group. In your add function, you the current value to the array and assign the first value to a 'min' property of the group. In your remove function you remove values, you remove the current value from the array and then assign the first value to the 'min' property (and check if the list is empty, in which case set it to undefined or something along those lines).

You functions will look something like this:

```
function add(accessor) {
    var i;
    var bisect = crossfilter.bisect.by(function(d) { return d; }).left;
    return function (p, v) {
        // Not sure if this is more efficient than sorting.
        i = bisect(p.valueList, accessor(v), 0, p.valueList.length);
        p.valueList.splice(i, 0, accessor(v));
        p.min = p.valueList[0];
        return p;
    };
};
function remove(accessor) {
    var i;
    var bisect = crossfilter.bisect.by(function(d) { return d; }).left;
    return function (p, v) {
        i = bisect(p.valueList, accessor(v), 0, p.valueList.length);
        // Value already exists or something has gone terribly wrong.
        p.valueList.splice(i, 1);
        p.min = p.valueList[0];
        return p;
    };
};
function initial() {
    return function () {
        return {
            valueList: [],
            min: undefined
        };
    };
}
```

'accessor' is a function to get at the value you want the minimum of, like in reduceSum. Call each of these functions to return the function you use in the corresponding place in the .group(add, remove, initial) function.

This code is pretty much ripped straight out of [reductio](https://github.com/esjewett/reductio), so you could also use reductio and do:

`var dateDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {return d3.time.day(d.date);});
var dateDimGroup = reductio().min(function (d) { return d.amount; })(dateDim.group());`

Your dateDimGroup will then have a 'min' property that should give you the minimum amount for every date.

Comment: This seems ideal. However I have tried this, using reductio and the code above, and the chart isn't being populated and no y-axis?

Comment: You'll have to provide your charting code if you want help on that. I'd guess that if you are using dc.js you need to add .valueAccessor(function(d) { return d.min; }) to your chart so that it knows where to look for the value.

Comment: Hi, I've had another go at it but I'm still not able to get the chart displaying properly, I'm sure I'm doing something silly. Here is a jsfiddle showing what's happening http://jsfiddle.net/northside45/u59ry898/

Comment: You need to use .valueAccessor(function(d) { return d.value.min; }). Sorry about the misdirection there. I forgot the valueAccessor deals with the full group and not the value. If you are seeing a problem loading reductio on your console (I was), you may need to change the URL to rawgit.

Comment: Thanks Ethan, that works great. I've just added a filter to select the past 7 days. That works fine when I'm not using the reductio group, so I presume that I need to do some thing with refreshing the valueAccessor? Thanks for your help with this, it's taking a while to get my head round it! Have a look here and you'll see what I mean - http://jsfiddle.net/northside45/u59ry898/

Comment: Sorry, also if I add say a pie chart to select between the 'types', this again stops the minimum group from displaying. I presume this is all the same thing?

Comment: This is happening because d.value.min becomes undefined for groups with no records, which dc.js doesn't like. Change to using .valueAccessor(function(d) { return d.value.min ? d.value.min : 0; }) and you should be in good shape. Most likely the same issue with the pie chart as well. Good luck!