# dc.js/d3.js - min/max value from group per category

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, charts, dc.js

I hate creating a new post to ask this, but since I'm still new, I cannot comment on posts yet.

I basically have the same question as [dc.js - min value from group per day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547347/dc-js-min-value-from-group-per-day)

But since the jsfiddle isn't up anymore, I cannot see how they resolved the question.

```
var data = [
    {category: 'A', ..., amount: '13', categoryCount: 1},
    {category: 'A', ..., amount: '13', categoryCount: 0},
    {category: 'B', ..., amount: '10', categoryCount: 1},
    {category: 'A', ..., amount: '3', categoryCount: 1},
    {category: 'C', ..., amount: '27', categoryCount: 1},
    {category: 'A', ..., amount: '11', categoryCount: 1},
    {category: 'B', ..., amount: '18', categoryCount: 2},
    {category: 'C', ..., amount: '19', categoryCount: 1},
    {category: 'C', ..., amount: ' ', categoryCount: 1},
    {category: 'C', ..., amount: '22', categoryCount: 1}
];
```

I would like to have an area graph containing the minimum (and maximum) values for each category.

I now have

```
var bar_graph = dc.barChart("#bar_chart");
var bar_graphDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.category;});
var bar_graphGroup = bar_graphDim.group().reduceSum(d.categoryCount);
var dateDimGroup = reductio().min(function (d) { return +d.amount; })(bar_graphDim.group());
var dateDimFGroup = remove_empty_bins(dateDimGroup);
bar_graph
    .width(150).height(60)
    .dimension(bar_graphDim)
    .group(dateDimFGroup)
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {return d.value.min;})  //added a solution
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .gap(2)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticY(true)
    .elasticX(true)
    .yAxisLabel("counts");
var bar_graphGroupMax = bar_graphDim.group().reduceSum(d.categoryCount);
var dateDimGroupMax = reductio().min(function (d) { return +d.amount; })(bar_graphDim.group());
var dateDimFGroupMax = remove_empty_bins(dateDimGroupMax);
bar_graphMax
    .width(150).height(60)
    .dimension(bar_graphDim)
    .group(dateDimFGroupMax)
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {return d.value.max;})
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .gap(2)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticY(true)
    .elasticX(true)
    .yAxisLabel("counts");
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you've already got a dimension and group, then the answer in the linked question is pretty comprehensive. If you are stuck at an earlier step, then let us know what you've done so far and what  is not working and people will do their best to help.

Comment: I've tried: 
var dateDim = facts.dimension(function (d) {return d3.time.day(d.date);});
var dateDimGroup = reductio().min(function (d) { return d.amount; })(dateDim.group());
But that didn't do it.  I'm not sure what to do...

Comment: So dateDimGroup.all() doesn't give you the minimums per day? I'd expect it to do that. Or are you not sure how to get this into a dc.js chart?

Comment: BTW, looks like your d.amount is a string, so you'll actually want to `var dateDimGroup = reductio().min(function (d) { return +d.amount; })(dateDim.group());` so that it sorts it as a number.

Comment: I added to the data to reflect better what I have and added code to the question.  What am I missing?  I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: a.group.all is not a function (dc.min.js:20)"

Comment: See below. Looks like you are missing a parens.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
var dateDimGroup = reductio().min(function (d) { return d.amount; }(dateDim.group());
```

I don't think that even executes, does it? I'd want you to have:

```
var dateDimGroup = reductio().min(function (d) { return +d.amount; })(dateDim.group());
```

Comment: I have "return +d.amount" but I am still getting an error message "TypeError: a.group.all is not a function (dc.min.js:20)"

Comment: I fixed the parens. issue.. but now the graph is blank. :/

Comment: I added .valueAccessor(function(d) {return d.value.min;}) to my graph variables and that fixed it.

Comment: How does max work?  I'm not seeing max values when I should.

Comment: Please create a working example on JSFiddle or something similar and I'll be happy to look at it! At the least, you need to post your complete code on SO here for me to answer the question about max. Probably best to open a new question in that case.